# checking list of floats for an integer

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list of float numbers like below:
I know they are float because I typecasted them, while taking them as input.

A = [1.0, 3.0, 3.5, 5.0]

I need to check this list for integers, something like

> if any(elements of the list is not an integer):
>
> > then do something

I am still new to python and I would like to know what is the most compact way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"If not all elements of A are integral":

```
if not all(x.is_integer() for x in A):
```

or equivalently, using your phrasing (at the cost of N `not` operations instead of one):

```
if any(not x.is_integer() for x in A):
```

While it is quite legible (basically English), to understand how to write it yourself, you need to first know about [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), then understand [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator-expression). You will also need [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [`float.is_integer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=is_integer#float.is_integer).

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly for me. I tried something similar but I used is_integer == False instead of if not and it did not quite work well. 
Thank you!

Comment: `x.is_integer() == False` should be equivalent to `not x.is_integer()` (just stylistically off). `x.is_integer == False` compares a _function_ (rather than an invoked function's return value) to a boolean, which is obviously never going to be equal.